# Grid on view in Lotus Notes 7

Tags: view, grid, lotus-notes

In the view propreties I set Grid - Dashes and Dots , color Black. But the grids are only horizontally. I want both vertical and horizontal.

The header style is Beveled. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native Notes applications cannot produce vertical dash-dots grids to simulate a grid. A View in Notes is record (or document) oriented. The grid setting in the view appears in version 8+. I tested dash-dot and it appears to be there, if you increase your line height it should be visible. The dash dots appear to be standard and not variable to font size.

Comment: well, in other lotus notes application i have 3 views and I set to all 3 both vertical and horizontal grids..

Comment: @FlorinMihalache Are the vertical gridlines displayed in the Notes client or a browser client? If you have it in another view, simply copy the technique from those 3 views to your new one (and post it here, because none of us can do it in the Notes client)

Comment: I just modified a view in a test database, and I do in fact see vertical grid lines in the Notes client in addition to the horizontal.  It's an 8.5.3 client, and I didn't do anything special in the view other than selecting the grid style.  However, have to say: it's really intensely ugly, particularly with the 'dashes and dots' style. I would never do this in a real application.

Comment: I just had a look in Notes and can see the setting in the view properties. It renders correctly for me. What version are you using ? I have amended my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the first column of the view, if it's not categorized, both vertical and horizontal grids are shown. As soon as you change the column to categorized, the view only shows the horizontal grids.